# mysql_real_escape_string with singleton database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I get the following error on my php pages that use database functions:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()
>   [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user
>   'apache'@'localhost'

I know I have to have a working connection to my database, but here is the 'problem'. The class that connects to my database looks like this:

```
class Database
{
    private static $instance = null;
    private static $conn;

    private function __construct()
    {
        try {
            self::$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'user', 'database');
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $errorpager = new CustomPageGenerator();
            $errorpager->generateErrorPage("Connection to database failed. Please try again later.");
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        try {
            if (self::$instance == null) {
                self::$instance = new Database();
            }
            return self::$instance;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $errorpager = new CustomPageGenerator();
            $errorpager->generateErrorPage("Connection to database failed. Please try again later.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        try {
            return self::$conn->query($sql);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $errorpager = new CustomPageGenerator();
            $errorpager->generateErrorPage("Connection to database failed. Please try again later.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use the Singleton pattern for this. But even though I put a

```
Database::getInstance();
```

at the very beginning of my code to open up the connection I keep getting this error. How do I correctly open up the connection so that I can use the mysql_real_escape_string() function?

Thanks.

**And here is le fix**

Added this function to the Database class:

```
public static function getConnection()
{
    self::getInstance();
    return self::$conn;
}
```

Replaced every single mysql_real_escape_string( with mysqli_real_escape_string(Database::getConnection(),

Comment: First of all there is `)` missing in the function call of `mysqli`, that means connection to the database is not created. Do you get any error while connecting to the database using `new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'user', 'database');`

Comment: Yeah, that's because I "censored" out my real username and password and accidentaly removed a ). Fixed that error.

Comment: Do you get any error while connecting to the database using `new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'user', 'database');` ?

Comment: Nope. The weird thing is: I have, for example, a function to register a new user to my website. I can fill in the register form, press the register button and then get a list of these errors. But when I go look into my database with phpmyadmin, there's a new row, but all the columns are empty.

Comment: `Mysqli` and `Mysql` use different connections that might be the problem. You cannot use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when your connecting to the database using `mysqli`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

That is from a different library than `mysqli`, maybe that's why there is no connection?

From the [`mysql_real_escape_string` page in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

> string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource
>   $link_identifier = NULL ] )

This is the definition for the second parameter, `$link_identifier`.

> The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the
>   last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is
>   found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with
>   no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING
>   level error is generated.

---

A possible, but kind of ugly solution, is to just add a wrapper to the real_escape_string method on your mysqli instance in your db singleton.

```
public function escapeString($value){
    return $this->conn->real_escape_string($value);
}
```

Another alternative may be to use the procedural version for mysqli library (although, I haven't actually tried to see if you can mix both, but I think you can): `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: Is there a way I could alter my Database class instead? I have dozens of mysql_real_escape_string() functions, but only 1 place where I connect to my database.

Comment: If you don't want to remove all the mysql_real_escape_string functions, you can try changing the call to `mysqli_real_escape_string`. I haven't tried it but that may work. This is so long as your connection is established before calling it. Probably not the best solution to have mysql_real_escape_string every where. But this could be a quick fix.

Comment: For a better solution, you can take a queue from mysqli prepared statements. See if you can refactor your class to use that instead. That way you can move your escape string functionality into your class during query execution instead. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: I could try to replace all mysql_... with mysqli_... but this function takes 2 parameters. 1 connection and 1 string to escape. This requires a whole lot of refactoring (we're talking maybe a few thousand lines of code). Also, my Database::getInstance() function doesn't return a connection, it returns a database instance. So that means even more refactoring :D I only encountered this problem just now because my webhost throws this problem, but my development environment did not.

Comment: Good point. I didn't realize that about the mysqli version. Maybe you can convert you code to use the mysql procedural functions. It works pretty much the same, except it's not object oriented.

Comment: I've found an easy way to refactor everything quite easily by adding a new simple function to the Database class. Check question for solution. Thanks for the help!